# insert data if the date time is different

Tags: php, sql, database

I have 2 tables: `reservations_client`  and `tables_clients`

The `reservation_client` has 3 fields:

> `id`, `name_client`, `date`, `table`

The `table_clients` has 2 fields:

> `id`, `name_table`

When a client wants to reserve they put his name, the date, and choose a table, but there is a problem: 2 clients cant use the same table.

What I need is it to only insert data into the database when the date is different. If the date is the same (i.e., someone's already using the table), it should send an error;

I tried using an unique key but it sends me an error even if the date is different.

My PHP code:

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO reservations_clients (user, number_person, table, date) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['user'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['number_person'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['table'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['date'], "text"),

  mysql_select_db($database_conexionbdd, $conexionbdd);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $conexionbdd) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($database_conexionbdd, $conexionbdd);
$query_table = "SELECT * FROM tables";
$table = mysql_query($query_table, $conexionbdd) or die(mysql_error());
$row_table = mysql_fetch_assoc($table);
$totalRows_tables = mysql_num_rows($table);
```

And the form clients fill out:

```
      <form method="post" name="form1" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
      <table align="center">
          <tr valign="baseline">
            <td nowrap align="right">Number_person:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Number of persons" value="" size="32"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr valign="baseline">
            <td nowrap align="right">table:</td>
            <td><select name="numero_mesa">
              <?php
do {  
?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row_table['idtable']?>" <?php if (!(strcmp($row_tables['idtable'], $row_table['idtable']))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>><?php echo $row_table['name_table']?></option>
              <?php
} while ($row_table = mysql_fetch_assoc($table));
?>
            </select></td>
          <tr>
          <tr valign="baseline">
            <td nowrap align="right">date:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fecha"  size="32" id="datepicker" /></td>

          </tr>
<tr>          
  <td nowrap align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Enviar"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php echo $row_user['user']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1">
      </form>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: 1) Don't put your code off-site... edit it into your post. 2) Don't use mysql_* functions. They're deprecated. Instead check out PDO and read up about it in [this tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). 3) WHen you say you've set a unique key, have you set the restraints on *both* table and date, or just one of the columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused about how you're using your database setup; seems the only issue is with the `reservation_client` table.

It looks like when you set the unique constraint, you only included `table` as a unique key instead of both `table` and `date`. One sets a unique key on one column, one sets it on the combination of columns. This combination as opposed to one column is extremely important. To fix this, go to the database you're working in, remove any unique keys in the `reservation_client` and :

```
ALTER TABLE `reservation_client` ADD UNIQUE (`table`, `date`);
```

Essentially what this does is say that in order to insert an entry, there can't be any row that has the same `table` and `date` values. It essentially sets a unique combination instead of a unique key. You're going to want to make sure you handle the error that's returned, whether that means catching it within your PHP or setting some kind of `ON DUPLICATE KEY` action in your query. I'm not sure the exact circumstances, so you'll have to play around with that.

Comment: ok..it may work. but: lets see, the 1st client get: table="1" and date="12/12/2013"..  then... there is a second cliente who wants the table="1" but with a different date time..   .. i think it should send a error because both fields are unique..

Comment: @KeyKenkay It shouldn't throw an error, specifically because what we're doing is adding a combination of rows as a unique key instead of just one row. Give it a try (run the query).

Comment: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'table_id'

Comment: @KeyKenkay Are you running the query above or are you adding unique constraints in a manager like phpmyadmin?

Comment: i think i shouldn't use an unique key.. because.. in the table.. it should repeat the tables_id.. but with a different date.. in every record... i added the unique keys to table and date.. now.. im trying to add some data.. to test it

Comment: @KeyKenkay Adding a unique key to `table` is **NOT** what you want to do. You want to add a *combined* unique key to `table` AND `date`.

Comment: that should work... but i'm new with php ...so, i think i should search for a while about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just query first if the table and date is present in the database.

```
 Select * From reservation_clients Where Date = $date And table = $table
```

if the result is empty then you can proceed to insert the data.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use where condition like this

```
$q_num = mysql_query('select * from reservations_client where date = "the date the  client chose" and table = "the table the client chose"');
$r_num = mysql_num_rows($q_num);
```

and make a condition if $r_num is > 0 then send error, else insert data

Answer (score 0):

if you are using php, get the date to the server side. Then, if you need second by second accuracy you can just compare those as strings

```
if($dateFromDB==date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
{
// go ahead and do your business
}
```

if you are looking to have 2 different days however, you can use the following

```
$today=explode(" ",date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

$today=$today[0];

$dateFromDB=explode(" ",$dateFromDB);

$dateFromDB=$dateFromDB[0];

if($dateFromDB==$today)
    {
    // go ahead and do your business
    }
```

Comment: give me a second to test it